# Divs are overlapping when left column div is greater than right column div

Tags: css, html

I'm creating multiple 3 column divs on a page. I noticed that if the left column div (data_cell1) is longer than the right column div (data_cell3). The div below goes up into the div above and overlaps it.

What do I need to change in my css to allow there to be separation between each div wrapper?

If the left column div and right column div are the same size, then I don't have this problem.

Here's the code example:
http://jsfiddle.net/huskydawgs/UMf3k/77/

```
      <div class="wrapper-data">
    <div class="data_row">
      <div class="data_cell1">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
            </div> 
      <div class="data_cell2">

      </div>
        <div class="data_cell3">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
      </div>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper-data">
    <div class="data_row">
      <div class="data_cell1">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,</p>
            </div> 
      <div class="data_cell2">

      </div>
        <div class="data_cell3">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</p>
      </div>
      </div>
  </div>


  <div class="wrapper-data">
    <div class="data_row">
      <div class="data_cell1">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,</p>
            </div> 
      <div class="data_cell2">

      </div>
        <div class="data_cell3">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</p>
      </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Here's my css.wrapper-data {
position:relative;
width:100%;
border: 1px solid red;
margin: 30px 0 5px 0;
}

.data_row {
height:100%;
white-space:nowrap;
}

.data_cell1 {
width:47%;
display:inline-block;
white-space:normal;
float: left;
}

.data_cell2 {
width:6%;
display:inline-block;
white-space:normal;
}


.data_cell3 {
width:47%;
display:inline-block;
white-space:normal;
}

Comment: Please put your CSS into your post, rather than a comment. It is not formatted for us to read easily in the comments and will most likely get your question passed over.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `float` on some elements you need to `clear` after to make the parent take the complete height, I use this technique:

```
.data_row:after {
  content:" ";
  display:block;
 clear:both;
}
```

You can see more about this [here](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/) and your demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UMf3k/80/)

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow: hidden` (or anything different than `visible`) to elements which contain floating elements.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/UMf3k/81/)